# Как принять Gsm звонок на компьютер?

Tags: ip

Подскажите как принять звонок gsm на компьютере? А также иметь возможность позвонить на указанный номер и включить записанный голос? Какие устройства и программы для этого нужны?

Answer (score -1):

Программ не знаю, самому нужно, вот системы есть: Asterisk, OpenPBX, FreePBX. Их можно установить на виртуалку.
Некоторые из них умеют работать с некоторыми модемами, надо изучать.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос